# Como puedo llamar desde un menu por botones en un Formulario (Windows Forms) otro formulario que ya posee una instancia en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

**Esta es la instancia que  utilizo para pasar datos de otro formulario a mi FrmProductos**

```
public static FrmProductos GetInstancia()
        {
            if (_instancia == null)
            {
                _instancia = new FrmProductos();
            }
            return _instancia;
        }
        //Creamos un método para enviar los valores recibidos
        //a la caja de texto txtIdcategoria
        public void setCategoria(string IdCategoria, string Nom_Categoria)
        {
            this.txtIdCategoria.Text = IdCategoria;
            this.txtNom_Categoria.Text = Nom_Categoria;

        }
```

**Y esta es la conexion que utilizo pero no me sirve**

```
private void btnProductos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           OpenChildForm(FrmProductos.GetInstancia(), sender);

        }
```

[image: Quiero hacer una coneccion que cuando seleccione el boton Productos me abra el formulario Productos]
Quiero hacer una coneccion que cuando seleccione el boton Productos me abra el formulario Productos

Answer (score 0):

Deberías pensar en utilizar el patrón Data Transfer Object (DTO) para este tipo de cosas. Hay muchas soluciones dependiendo de que tenes que llenar, estaria bueno que agregues un poco mas de info como ser, si vas a llenar un DataGridView, un ComboBox, varios TextBox, etc. Pero te tiro varias posibles soluciones.

**primera solución:**

Dado que tenes varios productos voy a asumir que vas a llenar un DataGridView, por lo cual te recomiendo crear un pequeño DTO_Productos con los datos que necesitas mostrar:

```
 public class DTO_Producto // esta clase la vas a usar para llenar los datos
            {
                //a modo de ejemplo hago de cuenta que el producto tiene estos 3 atributos
                public string IdProducto { get; set; }
                public string Nombre { get; set; }
                public string Descripcion { get; set; }
            }
```

Luegos modificas el constructor del formulario llamado:

```
private IList<DTO_Producto> productosParaCargar;//atributo del formulario llamado
    
    //de esta forma obligas a que el formulario que lo llame le tiene que pasar una lista con los datos
    public frm_productos_llamado(IList<DTO_Producto> productos)
    {
        productosParaCargar = productos;
    }
```

De esta forma ya vas a tener una lista con los datos para cargar en el contenedor que quieras.
Luego desde el formulario que llama creas el DTO y llamas al constructor del formulario y se lo pasas como parámetro:

```
private void BotonQueLlama_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       IList<DTO_Producto> productosParaCargar = new List<DTO_Producto>();

       DTO_Producto dto1 = new DTO_Producto();
       dto1.IdProducto = 1;
       dto1.Nombre = "Producto 1";
       dto1.Descripcion = "Producto 1 descripcion";
       productosParaCargar.Add(dto1);
       
       DTO_Producto dto2 = new DTO_Producto();
       dto2.IdProducto = 2;
       dto2.Nombre = "Producto 2";
       dto2.Descripcion = "Producto 2 descripcion";
       productosParaCargar.Add(dto2);

       //como ejemplo cargo 2 productos

      Form frm = new frm_llamado(productosParaCargar);
      frm.Show();
}
```

**Segunda solución:**

Si solo necesitas cargar 1 producto modifica el constructor con los datos necesarios:

```
public frm_productos_llamado(Tipo atributo1, Tipo atributo2,.......TipoN atributoN)
    {
        txt_1 = atributo1;
        txt_2 = atributo2;
        txt_N = atributoN;
    }
```

**Tercera solucion:**

Si estas trabajando contra una base de datos podes modificar el constructor para que reciba el id del producto y desde el formulario llamado obtienes los datos:

```
public frm_productos_llamado(int idProducto)
    {
        txt_nombre = service.getNombreProducto(idProducto);
        txt_descripcion = service.getDescripcion(idProducto);
    }
```

Todo esto es muy genérico, necesitaría mas info para darte un código mas detallado. Espero que te sirva, cualquier duda consulta.